# Wordpress cron isn't scheduled on amazon web services

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I'm trying to setup a cron to run every hour, it works fine on my local vagrant box, but it doesn't seem to schedule properly on aws(elastic beanstalk). Here's the code:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');
add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

function my_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
}

function do_this_hourly() {
    another_function();
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
}
```

is something wrong with this, or is something else at play?

I have w3 total cache installed both locally and on aws, so I don't think that would be to blame, as I've heard people mention it.

Thanks.

Comment: The WordPress cron API (by default) relies on a HTTP hit - if your setup is aggressively cached, WordPress might never actually be firing (or at least not frequent enough) to trigger cron. You might want to read into [how to "properly" set up cron in WordPress](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've started reading the link you provided, but I must note that the cron is never scheduled, it doesn't output when executing the following: $cron_jobs = get_option( 'cron' );
print_r($cron_jobs);, whereas locally, that same snippet shows me what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)?

Comment: Locally yes, not on the server.

Comment: Turn it on and activate the plugin, see if you get any errors.

Comment: Weird, turned WP_DEBUG on, deactivated and activated the plugin, no errors, but now the cron is scheduled in my staging environment(I created an if condition that checks the server variable for which environment it's in, and it only registers the cron for the staging, where WP_DEBUG is true...

Comment: Now added WP_DEBUG = true in all environments, and the live one still doesn't register.

Comment: I should also maybe add that this is a multisite installation.

Comment: You could use a cron manager plugin to see if the cron action is scheduled. This is a good one, don't be fooled by the warning that it has not been updated. [https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/fff-cron-manager/](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/fff-cron-manager/)

Answer (score 1):

As a general principal, you shouldn't do anything that requires an 'add_action' after the plugin activation hook. This is because WP loads and runs all plugins and THEN runs the new added one, and then does a re-direct. You have to set a DB option and hook into that. Here is the discussion from the CODEX:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Try doing this outside of the activation hook and see what happens.In other words, PHP runs through the whole Wordpress routine on each browser request. When you 'activate' a plugin, you actually fire two page requests to the server. This type of activity properly goes in the 2nd page request, which is the re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

You may use these steps to get it to work:`
**1. Setup an schedule**

```
function my_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['hourly'] = array(
        'interval' => 60 * 60,
        'display' => __( 'One houre' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'my_schedule' );
```

**2. Register the activation hook**

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation' );

function my_activation() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' );
    if( false == $timestamp ){
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
    }
}
```

**3. Add action on the event**

```
function do_this_hourly() {
    // The cron functionality and rest of your code here
}
add_action( 'my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly' );
```